# How to speed up the $lookup before aggregate $group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a requirement that need to `$lookup` something before aggregate  `$group`. But it gets pretty slow after I added the `$lookup` statement before `$group`.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from":"parent",
            "localField":"parent",
            "foreignField":"_id",
            "as":"parent"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$whateverId",
            datas: {$push: $$root}
        }
    }
])
```

If I commented out the lookup part, the runtime is just 0.300s. But now it's 4s.

Any ideas to speed up this query?

Comment: do u have index on `parent` field in both collections?

Comment: For my current collection, yes. I ran `db.myCollection.createIndex({parent: 1})` and can see the result in `db.myCollection.getIndexes()`. For the parent collection, I think the `_id` is a index by default.